# Do you know how to create this gallery box?

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

Does anyone of you know how to create this gallery box and text (with the line) from the image?
Can you help me, please?
I want to learn how to create this gallery box and add a magnifier icon when I hover over the image.
I also want to open the image when I click on it, in full size if possible.
May you please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: CSS-Grid or Flexbox. First would be easier: `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help me, I did this, and it's working. Although I didn't add a magnifier icon on hover.

```
<div id="portfolio">
            <div class="container-fluid w-75">
                <div class="row">
                <h3 style="color: #bb9754;"> Spoljašnost zgrade </h3>
                
                <hr style="background-color: #bb9754;">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-6 my-3">
                        <a class="portfolio-box" href="assets/img/portfolio/fullsize/1.jpg" title="Project Name">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="..." />
                           
                        </a>
                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```css
.container {
  width: "80vw";
  margin: "0 auto";
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  flex-basis: 15%;
}

.divider {
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery img {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="text">
      TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```css
#title{
font-size:20px;
color:#A5A195;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
#item{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;

}
.img{
  width:150px;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="title">
      SPOLJASNJOST ZGRADE
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="item">
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
      <a href=""><img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x300"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [answer]. Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).